# Sound problem after installing Lubuntu Desktop in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, audio-recording, sound-recorder

After installing `lubuntu-desktop` in Ubuntu 14.04 I can't record sound. Playback is OK.

[image]

I also install `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and `xfce4-mixer`

[image]

After installing pulseAudio volume control skype sound is ok. But I can't record with sound recorder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fresh install it works for me (I only installed Lubuntu not Ubuntu). But still don't know what the problem was. Guessing package overlapping was the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You may try using "Audacity". You can install this from Lubuntu Software Center. Although Audacity has more advanced functionality, it can work as a decent audio recorder. Audacity's "help" section is very good.

Comment: Audacity doesn't work. It has a bug.